Determining expiry on US patents with both patent term adjustment and patent term extension
In the case of a patent with both patent term adjustment (PTA) and patent term extension (PTE) in which cases will the PTA allow this extension to be longer than the PTE alone?
For example, US6967208 (US 6967208 patent expiry details):

Unadjusted expiry data: 2022-09-17
PTA days: 139 days
PTE days: 1526 days (https://ped.uspto.gov/api/queries/cms/pdfDocument/10245122/J79C2D0BRXEAPX4)

This gives an expiry date of either 2026-11-21 (PTE) or 2027-04-09 (PTA + PTE).
The FDA shows an expiry date of 2026-11-21 (https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/ob/patent_info.cfm?Product_No=001&Appl_No=202155&Appl_type=N)
The FDA defines this field as "The date the patent expires as submitted by the applicant holder including applicable extensions".
Can this FDA Orange Book expiry date be assumed to actually include all applicable extensions? (e.g. in this case the PTA wasn't applicable, perhaps as the examination and regulatory delays overlapped)
